# Select whole PictureBox in VB

Tags: vb.net, animation, timer

I need to make a simple If-Statement to make a `PictureBox` invisible while it's over another `PictureBox`.

Is there a way to select the area of a picturbox?

That's what I got for the If Statement :

```
moon.left-= 10

If moon.left = earth.right Then
    moon.visible=False
Else
    moon.Visible = True
End If
```

With my statement, it just disappears for a second.

I'm using a `Timer` for the animation.

Comment: You are simulating eclipses I think :)

Comment: You can use ZIndex for overlay.

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for the full width of the Images.  This assumes that you are moving the moon and that you don't have to account for the vertical axis:

```
If (moon.Left <= earth.Right AndAlso moon.Left >= earth.Left) OrElse (moon.Right <= earth.Right AndAlso moon.Right >= earth.Left) Then

    moon.Visible = False

Else

    moon.Visible = True

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this code, no need for an If-Statement:

```
moon.Visible = Not moon.Bounds.IntersectsWith(earth.Bounds)
```

The moon will be invisible when it intersects with the earth.